# Reference Hidden Job variables/elements in gitlab-ci.yaml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a cleanup step that needs to run against all applications but doesn't function as a parallel job. I basically just need to loop through list of apps but am struggling with the with the current formatting, ideally I wont duplicate the list already used for the Matrix / Parallel job.

Simplified example config below. It doesn't work but it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
.pico_service_list:
  - APP_NAME:
    - app_1
    - app_2
    - app_3

stages:
  - setup
  - cleanup

"Install depedencies":
  stage: setup
  extends: .install-dependencies
  parallel:
    matrix: !reference [.pico_service_list]

"Cleanup branch deployment":
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - |
      for APP_NAME in $(echo !reference [.pico_service_list]); do
        serverless remove --stage="$${APP_NAME}"
      done
```